# MATLAB Two Dice Thrown

Tags: matlab

I am asked to simulate the sum of 10000 dice rolls (Part A).

My problem is that variable `i` in the `for` loop keeps resetting to the number of games played rather than increasing. (so if my `i=2` and I throw dice 5 times (and the game ends) I want `i` to be `7`, but my `i` would go back to `3`.)

[image: Problem]

**Code for Part A**

```
firstwins=0;
 wins=0;
 lost=0;
 for i=1:10000
    reset =0; %reset
    roll =1; %number of rolls in a game
    chck=zeros(12); %array of zeros
    while reset==0 %game is not over yet
         a=randi(6); %roll a die
         b=randi(6); %roll a die
         c=a+b; %two die tossed
        if roll==1 %if this is the first roll of the game
            if c==7 || c==11 %if the sum equals 7 or 11
                wins=wins+1; %player wins so increment win
                 firstwins=firstwins+1; %#of times won by rolling only once
                 reset=1; %reset
            elseif c==2 || c==3 || c==12 %if the sum is either 2,3, or 12
                 lost=lost+1; %player loses
                 reset=1; %reset
            else %if the sum is neither 2,3,7,11, nor 12
                 roll=roll+1; %increment #of times die was tossed in a game
                 chck(c)=1; %store the sum
            end;
        else %if this is a reroll
            if c==7 %if the rerolled sum == 7
                lost=lost+1; %player loses
                reset=1; %reset
            elseif chck(c)==1 %if initial outcome occurred
                wins=wins+1; %player wins
                reset=1; %reset
            else %neither 7 or the initial outcome
                roll=roll+1; %increment the number of rolls in one game
            end;
        end;
    end;  
 end;
 prob=firstwins/10000;
```

Can anyone provide any guidance on Part C?

Comment: Overall, your simulation looks sound *except* that your dice roll never changes! When you do `roll = roll + 1` or reset the game, you need to increment `i` so you get a new sum from the dice! Your outer loop should be over a different variable, like for(sim_num = 1:t)

Comment: Another issue: if I were writing a simulator, I wouldn't do this `c(i)` stuff because you don't ex-ante know how many rolls you're going to need! Instead of `c(i)`, I would have some variable `current_dice_sum` and at the the appropriate points (i.e. reset of game or a new roll), I would do a `current_dice_sum = sum(randi([1 6],2,1))`

Comment: I would also separate (a), (b) , and (c) into different bits of code. Both (b) and (c) could use your simulator, but its a little different for(b) as you start with a specific initial roll. (a) doesn't need the full simulator. You can take your ` a=randi([1 6],2,t); c=sum(a,1);` and just a little more gives you (a). (Or you may have done that already!)

Comment: So, if I were to write a full simulator for a, b, and c, I need to make a randi for each for loop iteration, correct? I wrote my code like that before changing to a=randi([1 6],2,t);
 c=sum(a,1);

Comment: Also, I am not sure if t=10000 meant throw dice 10000 times or play 10000 games. Any suggestions?

Comment: hmmm, good point. Yeah, you could just use your current system and do t=10000 dice rolls. You could argue it either way. A random variable could be the dice roll, and I'm sampling that, or the random variable in question is whether the game is won or lost, and I'm samplign that.

Comment: Fixed my code. How do I start with C with this code I have for part A?

Comment: Isn't pmf a function (graph)? wins/10000 is just one value. Do I need to do this 10000 games 10000 times and divide by 10000 in order to get pmf?

Comment: probability mass function is a function mapping an outcome of a random variable to the probability of the outcome occurring. You gotta figure out what random variable they're asking about. (I don't know.) Anyway, gl!

Comment: The way I understand the task: a) generate 1000 sums of two random dice rolls. Then check for winning chance on the first roll (statistic stuff) b) suppose the first roll is a 5. How many additional rolls are needed to win the game? (again statistical over 1k samples) However we want to know the propability not the actual amount. c) full scale simulation. Calculate the winning propability for 1k samples and average them. Note: All above values may also be computed analytically (e.g. for reference).

Comment: To answer your question with the for loop: it is resetting, because for i = 1:n is not equal to for(i=1;i<=n;++i) that you may know from other programming languages. If your familiar with java, its somewhat similar to for(int i : [array]), so it iterates over each element in the vector 1:n rather then increasing i on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The MATLAB way to solve part A:

```
t = 10000;
winners = [7 11];

rolls = randi(6, 1, t) + randi(6, 1, t);
numWinners = sum( ismember(rolls, winners) );

numWinners/t
```